# Facing issue while sending a GET request with error 415

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect to  an endpoint and get data which is in XML format using HTTPUrlConnection API . Yet following code is strangely returning 415 error . I am not able to understand why GET request would got 415 error. I have tried setting Content type in request but it does not help

Also I have tried same task with OkHttpClient library and it is working fine. I have given the code for okHttpClient as well :

Please help

```
    try {
         url = new URL("xxx");
     }
     catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }


     try {
         HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

         con.setRequestMethod("GET");

         /*con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml;type=feed;charset=utf-8");*/


         con.connect();

         System.out.println(con.getInputStream().toString());

         /*OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

         Request request = new Request.Builder()
                 .url("xxx")
                 .method("GET", null)
                 .build();
         Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();*/

         

     } catch (IOException  ex) {

         ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: What about accept header?

Comment: I feel stupid now , yes @zolty13 it worked .thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Accept` Header resolved issue.